# Clone sandbox option is not working. I want it to clone Courioo03 sandbox for testing and staging

Tags: administration, sandbox-clone

[image]I want to clone my sandbox Courioo03 for testing but the option to clone isn't showing there.
What could be the solution for testing and staging using an enterprise edition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unfortunately you cannot recently Summer 2019 release hit preview sandboxes and the one you are trying to clone is from CS75 pod which is in the latest release whereas production is still running in spring 2019. They will get upgraded to Summer 2019 on june 15 post which you should be able to clone.

From [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=data_sandbox_clone.htm&type=5):

> NOTE You can only clone sandboxes that are on the same major
>   Salesforce version as the production org. During the transition to a
>   major release, some sandboxes get upgraded before others. To determine
>   the Salesforce version for your production and sandbox orgs, see this
>   [knowledge article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000220248&type=1&language=en_US). To determine when your production org or sandbox
>   gets upgraded, see the Salesforce maintenance schedule.

Comment: so, what I can do to counter this ? What could be the possible solution ?

Comment: so you cannot clone from 'Courioo03' since its in a preview pod. if you need to clone this you have to wait till june 15th, the other option is clone from any other non-preview sandbox if you can

Comment: I had my enhancements in this sand box. 
I got ' test in same environment and deploy ' option in my mind. What you suggest ? Is that a good option for now ? I can't wait till 15 June.

Comment: Do you know the changed components? you can extract them and deploy them in a new sandbox that you are planning to create?

Comment: Thanks. Let me check 'changed components' and give it a try. Otherwise I have stop development to start testing in same sandbox.